# calculating correlation between columns in table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure that calculates the correlations between some columns in a temporary table.

I have a query which produces a temporary table like below,

```
 Date         USA     JAPAN    FRANCE   UK 
 2018-01-01   5       3.2      1.6      2.8
 2018-01-02   6.8     8.2      0.9      3.5
 2018-01-03   4.3     6.2      3.3      2.1
 2018-01-04   3.9     6.2      4.5      7.8
 ...
 2018-01-31   7.6     5.1      4.7      5.1
```

I want to calculate the correlations between the all the columns. The query below does exactly that.

```
SELECT 
(Avg(SeriesA * SeriesB) - (Avg(SeriesA) * Avg(SeriesB))) / (StDevP(SeriesA) * StDevP(SeriesB))  
FROM myTempTbl
```

However the number of columns in my temporary table might change, i.e. another country might be added or deleted etc

What is the best way to calculate the correlation between all the columns to output results like below?

The result I want is something like below (correlations made up),

```
    Country1  Country2   Correlation
    USA       JAPAN      0.1
    USA       FRANCE     0.1
    USA       UK         0.1
    JAPAN     FRANCE     0.1
    JAPAN     UK         0.1
    FRANCE    UK         0.1
```

Comment: Ideally you should be changing the design of your table then. The problem here is you're not following normal form. The only solution, if your columns are subject the change, is to use dynamic SQL. If you design the table properly (so it would have the columns `[Date]` *(using reserved/key words as object names is also generally a bad idea)*, `Country` and `[A name that represents whatever that number is]`) this would be far easier, and wouldn't require a dynamic solution. Are you open to changing your design?

Comment: @Larnu yes open to changing the design. Currently I am using dynamic SQL but if there is a better solution then great

Comment: And how does your query relate to your data? There is no column `SeriesA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is what you are after, however, the results I get don't match yours (I get the value `0` for correlation for every row) This could be because your sample data implies much more data (which you haven't supplied, thus the expected results in your question is not representative of the sample data supplied). This should, however, at least push you in the right direction:

```
CREATE TABLE CountryData (DataDate date,
                          Country varchar(15),
                          SomeDecimal decimal(2,1)); --No idea what this represents

WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('20180101',5  ,3.2,1.6,2.8),
                ('20180102',6.8,8.2,0.9,3.5),
                ('20180103',4.3,6.2,3.3,2.1),
                ('20180104',3.9,6.2,4.5,7.8),
                ('20180131',7.6,5.1,4.7,5.1)) V([Date],USA,JAPAN,FRANCE,UK))
--Pivot the data. This is not dynamic, I am simply showing you what you need to data to look like.
--It was far quicker for me to take your existing data and pivot it, than transcribe it all in Normal Form
INSERT INTO CountryData
SELECT V.[Date],
       C.Country,
       CASE C.Country WHEN 'USA' THEN USA
                      WHEN 'JAPAN' THEN JAPAN
                      WHEN 'FRANCE' THEN FRANCE
                      WHEN 'UK' THEN UK
       END AS SomeDecimal
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('USA'),('JAPAN'),('FRANCE'),('UK')) C(Country);
GO
--How your data should look
SELECT *
FROM CountryData;
GO
--And now the (much simpler) non-dynamic solution
SELECT CDa.Country AS Country1,
       CDb.Country As Country2,
       (Avg(CDa.SomeDecimal * CDb.SomeDecimal) - (Avg(CDa.SomeDecimal) * Avg(CDb.SomeDecimal))) / (StDevP(CDa.SomeDecimal) * StDevP(CDb.SomeDecimal)) AS Correlation
FROM CountryData CDa
     JOIN CountryData CDb ON CDa.Country != CDb.Country
GROUP BY CDa.Country, CDb.Country
ORDER BY CDa.Country, CDb.Country;

GO
DROP TABLE CountryData;
```

Comment: thanks I'm just going through it now. One thing I noticed is just by changing decimal to float that some of the values are no longer zero

Comment: thanks the only thing missing was CDa.DataDate = Cdb.DataDate on the join, after that it is correct, thanks again

Comment: @mHelpMe you might want to include `DataDate` in the `SELECT` and `GROUP` by then (unless the date is in there `WHERE`).

Comment: This gives me always 0 as Correlation! I made an example here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=31a2f1ea40f3f42d0a6c4a7c1237268f where USA and SPAIN have the very same values but still 0 in correlation. I can't understand what's wrong with the query.

Comment: Because `0` divided anything is `0`, @Nicolaesse : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=c0455bcaef6963e7ea86eb709d8d7b9b)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT (Avg(x * y) – (Avg(x) * Avg(y))) / (StDevP(x) * StDevP(y)) AS ‘correlation’